# Issues with sstatic.net

Tags: support, cdn

I'm having issues with most of the SE sites if they use sstatic.com to server their [static files](http://sstatic.net/area51/all.css) (Like Area51).

Files are just not being downloaded. I tried on 2 different connections (3G and DSL) and 2 different devices (Mobile and Ubuntu (Firefox & Chrome)).

I don't see anything on the [twitter account](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/with_replies) nor on https://www.stackstatus.net/ so it might be a regional/localized issue.

According to firebug, sstatic.net is resolving to 190.93.246.58 if that helps.

Comment: https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/609296474015444992

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are seeing a combination of two issues.

Issue #1: DNS was down for several edge endpoints around the world heavily affected sstatic's DNS resolution. This has been resolved.

Issue #2 (possibly related): On the CloudFlare side, a route leak in Asia affecting that IP you resolve to (and thousands of others).

In the next few minutes, if the route leak is not resolved I will be turning off CloudFlare and directly serving all static assets out of our New York data center (unfortunately, we powered down Oregon yesterday). This in itself is not without risk as it's potentially a tremendous amount of bandwidth.

We'll provide updates on [@StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus) as they're available.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Everything is working normally now. (btw, I'm in Lebanon, so I might have been affected by the route leak).